# Ciclo para detección de colisión de figuras

Tags: java, ciclos

Estoy intentando hacer un ciclo que compare intersecciones entre objetos Rectangle del mismo arreglo.

Si encuentra uns intersección sale del ciclo, pero me marca un error al ejecutar:

> ```
> (Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException)
> ```

en esta línea:

```
boolean traslape = arregloRectangle[i].intersects(arregloRectangle[k]);
```

Codigo:

```
public class BasicProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int rango = 49;
        int min = 1;
        int contadorRectangle = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {            
            //Generación de valores aleatorios
            int posX = (int) (Math.random() * rango + min); 
            int posY = (int) (Math.random() * rango + min);
            int lado = (int) (Math.random() * rango + min);

            //Creación arreglo Rectangle
            Rectangle[] arregloRectangle = new Rectangle[10]; 
            //Creación del objeto Rectangle
            arregloRectangle[i] = new Rectangle(posX, posY, lado, lado);

            //Aumenta cada vez que se genera un objeto Rectangle             
            contadorRectangle++; 

            for (int k = 0; k < contadorRectangle; k++) {

                boolean traslape = arregloRectangle[i].intersects(arregloRectangle[k]);

                System.out.println(traslape);

                if (traslape) {
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Eso es porque tu arregloRectangle tiene posiciones nulas , ya que cada iteracion del primero for se inicializa el arreglo con tamaño 10, y solo inicializas una posicion que es arregloRectangle[i] = new Rectangle(posX, posY, lado, lado);, osea que antes de i y despues de todas la posiciones son nulas, y al entrar a este ciclo for (int k = 0; k < contadorRectangle; k++)  la segunda iteracion del primer for contadorRectangle es 2, por lo tanto estas accediendo a arregloRectangle[0] cuando es nulo. debes de inicializar arregloRectangle fuera del primer for, no dentro

Comment: @AlexisRodriguez Podrías elaborar una buena respuesta con ese comentario :P

Comment: @AlexisRodriguez entonces, ¿Entonces eso ocurre porque estoy generando los objetos Rectangle dentro del mismo ciclo que los comparo?, ¿me recomiendas que cree los objetos Rectangle en otro ciclo antes del ciclo de comparación?

Comment: lo comentado por @AlexisRodriguez pienso que soluciona su error, espero ponga una respuesta en base a su comentario, el lo explica en su comentario desde el porque hasta la solucion, "en pocas palabras" para solucionar su error esta linea `Rectangle[] arregloRectangle = new Rectangle[10];` borrela de ahi y pongala por ejemplo debajo de esta otra `int contadorRectangle = 0;` No porque los estes generando si no porque inicializas `Rectangle[] arregloRectangle = new...` en cada iteracion con lo que los datos digamos que usted ha introducido anteriormente se borran .Saludos

Comment: Muchas grácias, ya pude solucionarlo gracias a ambos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas, probablemente lo que quieres hacer es algo como esto:

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Rectangle[] rectArray = new Rectangle[10]; 

        RectangleCreation:
        for (int i = 0, length = rectArray.length; i < length; i++) {            
            rectArray[i] = generateRandomRectangle(1, 49);

            for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
                boolean intersectionOccurs = rectArray[i].intersects(rectArray[k]);

                if (intersectionOccurs) {
                    System.out.println("Colision al crear el rect numero: " + i);
                    break RectangleCreation;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static Rectangle generateRandomRectangle(int min, int max){
        max -= min;

        int posX = (int) (Math.random() * max + min); 
        int posY = (int) (Math.random() * max + min);
        int lado = (int) (Math.random() * max + min);

        return new Rectangle(posX, posY, lado, lado);    
    }
}
```

Valida que hace lo que quieres y comentas :P

Comment: No exactamente pero me sirvió, muchas gracias!